Error in Vs code while running c and java
My VsCode shows this " undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status" error whenever I try to run a code even though the code is correct. Some times it run soomtly and many time it shows this error agian and again
I tried running again and again but still no use

Please give some more context. Which command do you execute to compile stuff?
A good start would be to copy & paste the output from the commandline into a code section as part of your question here.
